# How to detect black contour in image using open-cv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image showed below (this image is a result of pre-processing of original image I had):

[image]

What I am trying to do is to detect the contour for the **Black region** bounded by 2 white regions (please note that white regions are not always solid and there could be 2, 3,... disconnected white region on top - for most of pictures the white regions are continuous; however, there are some examples where top white region is not continuous - Please see update section of my question to see example of non-continuous region)

Do you have any suggestion as how I can detect the boundary of black region and separate the black region?

**========= UPDATE Requested by Micka ========**

Example of non-continuous white region (this is happening only on top layer) - bottom layer is always continues solid white region

[image]

In this case like the picture showed above, I am okay with selecting a region like the one I showed below

[image]

**ideal selection**

[image]

**Original PHOTO**
I also included the original image for the above pre-processed image below in a case you are interested to work on pre-processing it. The pre-processing code I used and ended up with the image above is showed below:

```
img = cv2.imread('....tif')
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (29,1))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image]

Comment: context: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807919/how-to-measure-average-thickness-of-segmented-image-using-diplib (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73805144/how-to-change-back-the-labeled-image-to-a-form-that-cv2-can-read (3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792621/how-to-measure-average-thickness-of-labeled-segmented-image (referencing those for *context*, so others don't have to waste time suggesting solutions that have already been discussed)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for adding those. One of those questions is irrelevant to this question, the question which is relevant to this question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792621/how-to-measure-average-thickness-of-labeled-segmented-image which I already included it in the body of this question

Comment: Invert your image color, so the region is white surrounded by black

Comment: Can you show a sample image for "please note that white regions are not always solid and the could be 2 disconnected white region on top"?

Comment: This problem is easy when the white regions are connected and touching both sides. Please show typical samples such that this does not hold.

Comment: @Micka I added a sample picture of image with non-continues white region

Comment: @YvesDaoust for most pictures I have, both top and bottom white regions are continuous. However, there are some cases that only top white region is not continuous. I added a sample picture in the question

Comment: @fmw42 I tried using `cv2.bitwise_not(img2)` and then applying contour detection algorithm you suggested; however, it will give me an strange result for almost all pictures. The result is worst if the original image has 2 separated white top region (I showed an example of this type of photo above)

Comment: @Micka I added a sample picture of image with non-continues white region

Comment: if you are able to detect the region coarsely, you can use distanceTransform which's maximum value will be the thickness (as a radius, not as a diameter). Another way, if you can segment the region finer, is to put a minAreaRect around the black region that is surrounded by the white region in 2 directions. If the region is mostly horizontal, the approach of @YvesDaoust might be sufficient to find the fine-segmented region. The width (or height) of the minAreaRect is then the thickness of the region (as a diameter, not as a radius).

Comment: Show your original image before you processed it.  You may need to adjust the morphology to get a more continuous top line.

Comment: @fmw42 I add original photo to the question; however, I believe that changing image pre-processing is not good solution. I have more than 1000 photos and each can have different geometry and may need different image processing. What I am trying to find is a solution that can help me detect black region (and potentially thickness of it) for all images with same image pre-processing. In other words, I want to fix my image pre-processing and then have universal solution to detect black region

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your question from before. Why? I thought I answered it.

Comment: @fmw42 sorry for the confusion, no. This question is different. In the question you answered before, I tried to find the thickness of white layers; while this question is to try and detect and separate the black region bounded by 2 white regions. You suggested inversing the photo and I tried that; however, I didn't get a good result for it specially for the picture where the narrow white region on top is separate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"D:\OpenCV Projects\Black Contour\image.jpg")

img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 75])
upper = np.array([179, 179, 115])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

mask_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 1)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask_blur, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(img, [max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)], -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Here is all the processing the image went through during the execution of the above code:

BGR to HSV:

[image]

HSV to mask:

[image]

Mask to blurred mask:

[image]

Blurred mask to thresholded mask:

[image]

From here, simply detect the contour from the image above and draw it onto the image.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. I have a couple of questions. Can I ask why you changed the photo to HSV format? what's the benefit of doing this? my original photo is TIF format, can I still change it to HSV type? Also, I can see that you defined `lower` and `upper` bands for the photo. can I ask how you defined these values? is it some sort of general bandwidth that I can apply to all my photos? or it's specific to this photo I posted?

Comment: I same comment for thresholding looks like you chose 200 and 255 for the boundary, but I am not sure how you chose these numbers. Can you explain, please?

Comment: @Ross_you Hi! Didn't notice your comments at first. I used [OpenCV Trackbars](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html). Here is another answer of mine where I post the code for using trackbars to fine-tune the HSV values: [Digital image processing of corn kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606031/13552470)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach in Python/OpenCV that I tested on your short lines image. You may have to adjust for other images.

The idea is to apply vertical morphology to close up the spacing.  Then get the absdiff between he threshold version and the closed version. The clean up any small spots with a morphology open.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
image = cv2.imread("short_lines.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology close to connect space between lines
kernel = np.ones((45,1), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get absdiff of morph and thresh
diff = cv2.absdiff(thresh, morph)

# apply morphology open to clean up small spots
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
result = cv2.morphologyEx(diff, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# save results
cv2.imwrite("short_lines_close.jpg",morph)
cv2.imwrite("short_lines_diff.jpg",diff)
cv2.imwrite("short_lines_space.jpg",result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("diff", diff)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Morphology Close image:

[image]

Absdiff Image:

[image]

Final Result after Morphology Open:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Quick & dirty method:**

Scan every image column and count the transitions from black to white and conversely. Every time you find four transitions, the two middle ones give you the thickness. Keep the median value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, does angle of layer affect this approach? should I rotate image first and then count? Also, how can I detect transition from black to white? can I say when pixel value changes from 0 to 255, that's a transition? do we have function to do this in `cv2` or I need to implement this in a `for loop`?

Comment: @Ross_you: depends if you are after the vertical thickness or normal thickness.

Comment: I define thickness as the normal thickness. FYI, I also added my original photo to the question, if that helps. I am doing following image pre-processing: `kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (29,1))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)` 

however, as mentioned in my comment to to @fmw42, I don't want to change pre-processing and am looking for solution to detect edge and thickness with same pre-processing for all of my photos

Comment: @Ross_you: the ratio of the two thicknesses is the cosine of the angle. Close to 1 for small angles. You can find the angle by considering two distant columns.